# at most $ 4$ steps to convert from one prime $a$ to another prime $b$ if the intermediate number formed in the process is also a prime .

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

We have a prime number $a$ and we want to convert it into another prime number $b$   but we can either add a prime number to it or subtract a prime number from it and the intermediate number formed in the process should also be a prime   .
The solution says that if there exists some path such that we can do this , then the at most number of paths is 4 if we want it to done with minimum number of operations of addition and subtraction ? Can anyone prove this statement ?

eg if $a$ is $5$ and $b$ is $43$ then a path is $5$ >$2$>  $43$ i.e ($5$-$2$=$3$ is a prime and $43$-$2$=$41$ is a prime).Here path is of length $3$

Comment: Really?  Seems to me that I can find infinitely many primes with difference divisible by $2,3,5,7,11$, say...and I get a different path for each prime factor.  Or have I misunderstood the rules?

Comment: Oh, wait...am I only allowed one operation?  I was assuming I could iterate.  But if I am only allowed one operation, then surely there is at most one path?

Comment: The example doesn't help...it seems that you get more than one operation, no?  In your case...$43-5=38=2\times 19$ I could just add $19$ twice.  Or add $2$ nineteen times, yes?

Comment: Also:  the header suggests that you are trying to cap the length of a path, while the question itself asks about the number of paths.  Which did you mean?

Comment: @lul updated.i had done one mistake of not mentioning that the intermediate number formed in the process should also be a prime number .

Comment: Ah, well that is certainly an important detail.  Can you clarify whether you meant the length of the path (as in the header) or the number of paths (as in the question)?

Comment: So your problem says that whenever exists a path, the lenght of the path is at most $4$, right?

Comment: yes and the intermediate numbers that help us to reach b should also be prime .

Comment: But of course there are certainly paths of the form $2\to 5\to 2\to 5\to\cdots$ so you want to avoid loops.

Comment: yes with minimal number of additions and subtractions

Comment: Hint:  the difference between two odd primes is even, so you are badly constrained in the moves you can make from an odd prime.

Comment: Note:  adapting your example, isn't the path $7\to 5\to 2\to 43\to 41$ a path of length $5$ connecting $7$ and $41$?

Comment: 7->2->43->41 this is a better path as it has less number of add and subtract operations.

Comment: Well, ok.  Though you really need to edit your post for clarity.  My hint works...just separate two cases:  either $2$ occurs in your path or it doesn't.  If it doesn't, the path is very short indeed. If it does, then try to extend the path $p\to 2 \to q$ on either side.

Comment: Mind you, I still see paths of length $5$.  If $(p,p+2)$ and $(q,q+2)$ are twin prime pairs then you get $p\to p+2\to 2\to q+2 \to q$.  Can you shorten all of these?  As a concrete example, shorten $11\to 13\to 2 \to 19\to 17$.

Answer (score 0):

To get from $29$ to $41$ the shortest path is
$$
29 \to 31 \to 2 \to 43 \to 41.
$$

To make sense of the question, I think you have to interpret the "length" of
the path as the number of times the symbol $\to$ occurs between
two primes in the path, not the number of primes in the path.

To show that there is no longer path, consider that to "move"
from an odd prime to any other prime, the only possibilities
are to add or subtract $2$ in order to reach another odd prime,
or to subtract another odd prime to reach $2$.
Moreover, there is never a case where you can add $2$ twice in a row,
that is, never a case where $p$, $p+2$, and $p+4$ are all prime.

So let's make a connection graph with prime numbers as nodes and
possible "moves" as edges.
There are edges from the prime number $2$ to many other prime numbers,
but from each of those nodes there is at most one other edge.
The graph consists of $2$, 
some odd primes that are connected to no other odd primes,
and some pairs of odd primes $p, p+2$ that are connected to each other.
Some of the odd primes are connected to $2$, and there are no other edges.
There are not very many different cases to consider for what could be
the shortest path between two primes $p$ and $q$ if any
path between those nodes exists.